# Javascript ClearTimeout doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, cleartimeout

I'm looking for a solution for my code. My clearTimeout function doesn't work in the stop(); and start(); functions, does anybody know how to fix this?

The stop, start and reset button have all a setTimeout function. What I would like to do is that if is clicked at one of the buttons, the other two buttons have cleartimeout. But for somehow it doesn't working right now.

```
var isTimerStarted;
var timeOutElse;
var timeOut;
var opnieuw;

function start() {
    clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 1);
    x.start();
    isTimerStarted = true;
    timeOutElse = setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("scherm3").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("scherm2.2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 8000)
}

function stop() {
    x.stop();
    clearInterval(clocktimer);
    isTimerStarted = false;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("scherm4").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("scherm2.2").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    }, 4000)
}

function reset() {
    stop();
    x.reset();
    update();
    opnieuw = setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("scherm3").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("scherm2.2").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    }, 10000);    
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    clearTimeout(timeOutElse);
    document.getElementById("buttontimer").value = "Start";
} 

setTimeout(start, 5000);

function toggleTimer(event) {
    if (isTimerStarted) {
        stop();
        event.target.value = 'Start';
        clearTimeout(opnieuw);
        clearTimeout(timeOutElse);
    } else {
        start();
        event.target.value = 'Stop';
        clearTimeout(opnieuw);
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you detail on how it is not working right now please?

Comment: What is "x" in your example.
Can you post your HTML so we can see your problem in the code snippet editor?

Comment: Is `clocktimer` declared somewhere? It's not in your snippet. It should at the top, like others.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the code that isn't directly related to timeouts/intervals.

Comment: @YoannM the clearTimeout in my Reset function doesn't work. If I first click at stop/start and then reset, two settimeouts are running and I only want one of them.

Comment: I don't see the `reset` function being called anywhere? Is it an `onclick` on a DOM element?

Comment: @YoannM yes, it's declared like: var clocktimer;

Comment: @HopefulLlama yes, its like this:         <input type="button" value="Opnieuw" onclick="reset()" class="button2" id="opnieuw">

Comment: Are you getting any errors or exceptions in the console?

Comment: @HopefulLlama no...

Comment: @HopefulLlama mind that `setTimeout(start, 5000);` is still starting your timeouts after 5 seconds, whatever you click.

Comment: @YoannM is right. @annaneedshelp There could be a timing issue in your application. i.e: if you `reset `, before the `setTimeout(start, 5000);` occurs, it will still create the `timeoutElse` timeout.

Comment: It could be, but that still doesn't make sense why my cleartimeout at reset doesn't work, right??

Comment: When you click, you create timeouts. Then your 5s timeout gets executed and reassigns your timeout variables, so you lose the reference to those first ones, and they never get cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, from what I can tell.

But I think you might have forgot to remove a line from it.

`setTimeout(start, 5000);` is creating timeouts after 5 seconds whatever/whenever you click a thing.

It is what could create timing issues.

Here's a scenario that could happen:

- you click
- `toggleTimer()` -> `start()` -> create timeout and interval
- 5s later your `setTimeout(start, 5000)` executes and reassign your timeout and interval variables
- you re-click
- latest timeout and interval gets cleared, but not the first ones

Just to be safe, you could clear, at the beginning of each of your functions, the timeouts and intervals you're creating in the said function.

This way, you will always clear timeouts and intervals that gets created.

Comment: Is this not only for the 'start' function?

Comment: I've precised my thoughts in my answer.

Comment: I put my clearTimeout in my reset at the first line in the reset function and that one worked, thanks!